# prometheus/Thanos - How to find out index size of each label for a particular metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator

I am responsible for maintaining the metrics and labels. With each metric, different labels are coming some by default and some custom. We are using the Grafana agent along with Prometheus.

Is there any way to find out the index size of each label generated by particular metrics, so we can figure out the high storage-consuming label?
Ex. For the `node_cpu_seconds_total` metric we get labels such as `Job`, `method`,`Podname`, `location`,`instance_name`, `mode` etc. Can we find storage occupied by this each label?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [Cardinality management dashboards](https://grafana.com/docs/enterprise-metrics/latest/tenant-management/cardinality-management/) which can enable you to analyse your label usage and estimate storage consumption.

Besides that, it may be not exactly what you are looking for, because it relates to active series, not storage itself, but you can use [Mimirtool to calculate number of series for each metric](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/billing-and-usage/control-prometheus-metrics-usage/usage-analysis-mimirtool/). If your goal is to optimize storage consumption, it may be helpful as well.